# How to make latexmk hand over additional argument to lualatex?

Tags: luatex, latexmk

My document uses Lua to process additional command line parameters like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
  \catcode`\#=11
  \directlua{
    local i = 1
    while i <= #arg do
      name = arg[i]
      i = i + 1
      if name == "\jobname.tex" then
        break
      end
    end
    if i > #arg then
      tex.error("missing data argument!")
    end

    values = require(arg[i])
  }
\endgroup

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{r|l}
    Name & \directlua{tex.sprint(-2, values.name)} \\ \hline
    Age  & \directlua{tex.sprint(-2, values.age)}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For example, if I have a file `test.lua`:

```lua
return {
  name = "John Doe",
  age  = 42
}
```

I can compile my document with

```
lualatex test.tex test.lua
```

Now the need has arisen to compile my document with `latexmk`. Unlike `lualatex`, `latexmk` expects a list of files to process, so simply giving `test.tex test.lua` as arguments will not work because they are processed independently.

I can of course do this in a `.latexmkrc` file:

```perl
$pdf_mode = 4;
$lualatex = 'lualatex %O %S test.lua'
```

However, now I cannot change the data file on the command line anymore.

Is it possible to configure latexmk so that I can give the `test.lua` path on the command line like I can with `lualatex`?

Comment: What OS and Editor/Front End are you using?

Comment: @HerbSchulz I am on macOS, though my code should be portable to other OSes. Editor is VSCode though I don't really see how that is relevant.

Comment: It would be easy if you were using TeXShop and its lualatexmk engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the configuration on the commandline, eg

```
latexmk -pdflatex='lualatex test.tex test.lua' -pdf test.tex
```

Comment: Not what I hoped for, but at least scriptable. Thanks!